# How to count base clauses in another module in Prolog

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

In list.pl there is:

```
:- module(list, [people/1, friend/2]).

people([a, b, c, d, e]).

friend(a, c).
friend(b, c).
friend(c, d).
friend(c, e).
```

There may be another friend relations and people in list.pl.

In popular.pl I have:

```
:- module(popular, [friendCount/2]).
:- [list].


sum(A, B, S) :- S is A+B.

aggregate_all(count, friend(X, Y), Count).

friendCount(Person, Count) :-
  aggregate_all(count, friend(Person, X), C1),
  aggregate_all(count, friend(X, Person), C2),
  sum(C1,C2,Count).
```

I want this:

```
?- friendCount(c, Count).
Count = 4.
```

But I get this:

```
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `aggregate_all(count, friend(X, Y), Count).` in your `popular.pl` does what?

Comment: ?- aggregate_all(count, friend(X, c), C2).
Correct to: "list:friend(X,c)"? yes
C2 = 2.

Comment: that is when you call it from the prompt. but when you load the file, what does that line in the file *do*?

Comment: if you wrote `print(1).` in the file, what would *that* line do? try it. create new pl file, add `print(1).` there, and load the file. will it *print* the number `1` on loading that file?

Comment: So, C1 and C2 are not instantiated actually. Thanks.

Comment: Use `use_module` to load modules. Basically, never use `consult` or `[]` to load Prolog source files.